# Recursion: Why does function returns factorial of a number instead of returning 1?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

```
def fact(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * fact(n-1)


def rec():
    print fact(5)

rec()
```

[A question from newbie]

Python script.

This question remained in mind for a long time, let me explain my understanding so far on recursion.

In **rec()** function I called one more function **fact(5)**, now the process is went to fact(n) function.

Function calls itself until the base case.

**In else part**:

```
5 * fact( 4 )

5 * 4 * fact( 3 )

5 * 4 * 3 * fact( 2 )

5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * fact( 1 )
```

Now the value of n becomes 0, and **return 1**

**My question is, why the fact(n) function returns 120 instead of 1.**

```
def check(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 10
    else:
       return 20
     
print check(1) // Prints 10
print check(3) // Prints 20
```

I hope you understood my question.

Thank you.

Comment: `else: return n * fact(n-1)` so it takes the base case, returns it and adds it with the `n` of the function it called, repeat and so on and so forth until you get back up..

Comment: Because `fact(1)` is returning `1*1`, `fact(2)` is returning `2*1`, `fact(3)` is returning `3*2`, `fact(4)` is returning `4*6` and `fact(5)` is returning `5*24`

Comment: imagine the returns being nested. 1 is returned but it is passed on the outer return(s) (freely speaking)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You itself answering the question

**In else part:**

```
5 * fact( 4 )

5 * 4 * fact( 3 )

5 * 4 * 3 * fact( 2 )

5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * fact( 1 )
```

**then**

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * fact( 0 )
```

after that it goes in the if part that is returning 1

```
if n == 0:
        return 1
```

So expression is like this

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
```

=120

Answer (score 7):

Here's how the stack looks like when `fact(5)` is evaluated:

```
fact(5) = 5 * fact(4)
  fact(4) = 4 * fact(3)         
    fact(3) = 3 * fact(2)
      fact(2) = 2 * fact(1)
        fact(1) = 1 * fact(0)
          fact(0) = 1
          # no more recursive calls, unwind the stack
        fact(1) = 1 * 1 = 1
      fact(2) = 2 * 1 = 2
    fact(3) = 3 * 2 = 6
  fact(4) = 4 * 6 = 24
fact(5) = 5 * 24 = 120
```

Hope it helps. Each indent is what `fact(N)` returns.

Answer (score 2):

You already mentioned the answer in the question. Let me explain a bit more. When you do:

```
return n * fact(n-1)
```

It means, `return` "n" multiplied by value returned by `fact(n-1)`. so, in you last step, you mentioned:

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * fact( 1 )
```

`fact( 1 )` will be replaced by 1, and your `fact` will return `120`, i.e. `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1`.

For more details, read: [Recursive Functions](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/recursion2.html)

Answer (score 1):

So you have the initial understanding correct, when `n == 0` `fact` does return 1. But think about what it is returning that value to: the branch that called `fact(0)`, namely `fact(1)`. `fact(1)` then returns `1*1` to `fact(2)` and it crawls back up until you reach the original call and receive an overall calculation of `5*4*3*2*1*1`.